# This sample code won't compile

Tags: c++

I cannot understand the error message I get when I compile this code in a cygwin shell. The message is very long, but somewhere in the middle of this 1,000 line error it says:

> no matching call for operator <

What does this mean? Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

struct Grade{
 string id;
 int score;

  bool operator() (Grade& a, Grade& b){
        return a.id < b.id;   
    } 
};  

int main()
{   
    Grade g;
    set<Grade> gs;

    g.id = "ABC123";
    g.score = 99;
    gs.insert(g);

    g.id = "BCD321";
    g.score = 96;
    gs.insert(g);

    for(auto it : gs)
        cout << it.id << "," << it.score;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `set` stores its elements in sorted order, which requires your data type to have an `operator <` defined.

Comment: I see, how I could define it?

Comment: You might want to consider marking "solved" on your past questions: http://stackoverflow.com/users/4416304/xdprogrammer?tab=questions

Comment: Don't look at the middle error. Look at the top one!!!

Answer (score 10):

Sets require their element type to define the less than operator. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/?kw=set

You could define it like this (after the definition of Grade):

```
bool operator< (const Grade& a, const Grade& b){
    return a.id < b.id;
}
```

Comment: Where should I define this? When I add it on the struct it says, must take one argument

Comment: @XDProgrammer Outside of the definition of `Grade`

Answer (score 7):

`std::set` stores its elements in sorted order, which requires its element type to have an `operator <` defined for it. In this case, you need to define `operator <` for your `Grade` type.

```
bool operator < (const Grade& grade1, const Grade& grade2)
{
   return grade1.score < grade2.score;  // or other method of determining
                                        // if a grade is less than another
}
```

Or if you'd like to define it within the struct itself:

```
bool operator < ( const Grade& grade2) const
{
    return score < grade2.score;  // or other method of determining
                                    // if a grade is less than another
}
```

Comment: Looks like we both gave the same answer at the same time :). Should I delete mine?

Comment: @qbt937, I don't think that's necessary, who was to know who would answer first!

Answer (score 6):

You can create a `std::set<Grade>` if you overload the `operator<()` function for `Grade`. The function can be defined using a member function or a non-member function.

No matter which approach you take, the function has to be defined such that both the LHS and the RHS can be `const` objects.

Member function approach:

```
struct Grade{
   string id;
   int score;

   bool operator<(Grade const& rhs) const
   {
      return this->id < rhs.id;   
   }
};
```

Non-member function approach:

```
struct Grade{
   string id;
   int score;
}; 

bool operator<(Grade const& lhs, Grade const& rhs)
{
   return lhs.id < rhs.id;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank everyone for your help, Ive seen many solution, and this is my code, which sorts the ID in ascending order

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

struct Grade{
 string id;
 int score;

 bool operator< (const Grade& g) const {

    return this->id < g.id;
 }
}; 


int main()
{   
    Grade g;
   set<Grade> gs;

    g.id = "ABC123";
    g.score = 99;
    gs.insert(g);

    g.id = "BCD321";
    g.score = 96;
   gs.insert(g);

    for(auto it : gs)
        cout << it.id << "," << it.score << endl;; 

    return 0;
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is the updated code which compiles correctly. The Issue for "operator<" for `std::set` has been solved:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

struct Grade{
   string id;
   int score;

    bool operator<(const Grade& that) const
    {
        return this->score < that.score;   
    } 

    bool operator() (Grade& a, Grade& b){
        return a.id < b.id;   
    } 
};  

int main() {
    Grade g;
    set<Grade> gs;

    g.id = "ABC123";
    g.score = 99;
    gs.insert(g);

    g.id = "BCD321";
    g.score = 96;
    gs.insert(g);

    for(auto it : gs)
        cout << it.id << "," << it.score;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The comparison is being performed on `Grade` objects not strings.

Comment: @Captain.. if you have a look at the implementation of operator() two id are being compared there.

Comment: So, I did `a.id < b.id` does this not mean comparing strings? actually I want to compare the id instead of score

Comment: [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) requires `operator<` or custom comparator for  `Grade` which is not defined. `operator<` for strings is. Guess which one is causing the error.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I think that one cause , the error, I am not use to set Container, I just know vector,

Comment: There is no issue with the comparison of strings here. `operator<` is defined in `<string>` which is included. The only problem is here the missing `operator<` for `Grade`.